# Is there an Eclipse keyboard shortcut to open the SVN Console?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

#### Context

Eclipse has a view called *Console* which in turn hosts several other consoles one of which is the *SVN Console*. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Eclipse SVN Console]

#### Question

Is there an Eclipse keyboard shortcut to open the *SVN Console*?

#### What I've tried so far

- I've [googled](https://www.google.ch/search?q=eclipse%20%22svn%20console%22%20keyboard%20shortcut) but found nothing
- I've tried Eclipse's *Quick Search*; it finds the *Console* view but not the *SVN Console*
- I've looked in *Preferences* under *Keys* whether there is a command for *SVN Console* to which I could assign a keyboard shortcut but there wasn't
- I've put the cursor focus on the *Console* view and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times but the focus doesn't jump to the small button with the black downward arrow marked with the red rectangle in the above screenshot

#### Versions

- Eclipse 4.4
- Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not what your ask for, but might fit your needs, you could display the svn console automatically if I remember correctly through preferences :

`Window > Preferences > Team > SVN > Console : check Show Console automatically on on X (what you want)`